# Python pandas regex from google sheets

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to covert a google sheet regextract to python, either with using pandas or re.

new Google sheet column:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(F2,"([A-Z]+\-[0-9]+)"))
```

I am not sure how to apply it to the entire column, here was my attempt which resulted in error

```
df["newcol"] = df['oldcol'].re.sub(([A-Z]+\-[0-9]+)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re` is package from `python` and if you would like do within `pandas`

```
df["newcol"] = df["oldcol"].str.extract(r'([A-Z]+\-[0-9]+)')
```